# Chrome crashes when use XHR to send large file

Tags: javascript

I use XMLHttpRequest to send POST data to nodejs (expressjs api). The size of file about 200mb. When I do, Chrome crashes, but the Firefox doesn't. Does Chrome have a limited file size?

And how can I upload the large file via JavaScript?

This is my code send xhr request:

```js
// create http request API AI Engine
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.timeout = 3600000;
xhr.onload = function() {
  // reponse measage
  if (this.status === 200) {
    var errorArea = document.getElementById('error-area');
    errorArea.style.display = 'none';
    zip.files = {};
    // unzip File
    zip.loadAsync(this.response)
      .then(function(zip) {
        // will be called, even if content is corrupted
        for (const file in zip.files) {
          if (zip.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
            const fileObject = zip.files[file];
            fileObject.async('arraybuffer').then(function(fileData) {
              var fileSave = new Blob([new Uint8Array(
                fileData)]);
              // Save file
              saveAs(fileSave, fileObject.name);
            })

          }
        }

      }, function(e) {
        var errorArea = document.getElementById('error-area');
        errorArea.style.display = 'block';
        errorArea.innerHTML =
          '<strong>Error</strong> Cant not unzip file return.';
      });
    // get response stream data

  } else {
    var errorArea = document.getElementById('error-area');
    errorArea.style.display = 'block';
    errorArea.innerHTML =
      '<strong>Error</strong> Cant not analyze file: ' + this.statusText;
  }
};
// Handle when have error with xhr, show message
xhr.onerror = function(err) {
  var errorArea = document.getElementById('error-area');
  errorArea.style.display = 'block';
  errorArea.innerHTML =
    '<strong>Error</strong> Cant not analyze file: ' + this.statusText;
};
// Handle when have timeout with xhr, show message
xhr.ontimeout = function() {
  var errorArea = document.getElementById('error-area');
  errorArea.style.display = 'block';
  errorArea.innerHTML =
    '<strong>Error</strong> Cant not analyze file: Request time out';
};
// Add custom header
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.setRequestHeader('file-name', Date.now().toString() + '.zip');
xhr.setRequestHeader('file-length', data.byteLength);
// Send arraybuffer to server           
xhr.send(data);
});
```

Comment: Would help if you showed us the javascript you're using

Comment: Chrome can handle file size larger then `200MB`, the problem might be at another place. But without knowing the code it is not possible to tell.

Comment: Is that data payload compressed? Any way you can break it up and do several XHR requests instead of one?

Comment: I use jszip to zip the data and sent it by xhr request